# ng-model return value as an array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular.
I'm finding a way to return the ng-model value as an array.

```
<select ng-options="district.name for district in districts" ng-model="district"></select>

$scope.districts = [
    {
      name: 'A'
    },
    {
      name: 'B'
    },
    {
      name: 'C'
    }
]
```

So it will store an Object in `district` when I select one of the option.

```
{
 name: 'A'
}
```

But what I want is an Array storing Object. Just like

```
[
  {
   name: 'A'
  }
]
```

I found that `select[multiple]` is doing what I want. So I wonder is there any build-in method can do this on a single selection.

Answer (score 2):

Just have two option, first if to bind to an array of arrays, second is to manualy form the array from the selected value:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dropDownValues = [[{
      value: "Cat",
      name: "Cat"
    }], [{
      value: "Dog",
      name: "Dog"
    }]];
    vm.animal = vm.dropDownValues[0];
    /*
    // probably easier to just select the first element
    vm.animal = vm.dropDownValues[0].value;
    */
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp">

  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.animal" ng-options="animal as animal[0].value for animal in vm.dropDownValues">
  </select>
  
  <span>{{vm.animal}}</span>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

The other option:

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('exampleApp', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ExampleController);

  function ExampleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dropDownValues = [{
      value: "Cat",
      name: "Cat"
    }, {
      value: "Dog",
      name: "Dog"
    }];
    vm.animal = "Cat";
    vm.actualModel = [];
    
    vm.modelChanged = function(animal) {
    console.log(animal);
      vm.actualModel = [animal];
    };
    /*
    // probably easier to just select the first element
    vm.animal = vm.dropDownValues[0].value;
    */
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp">

  <div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    <select ng-model="vm.animal" 
      ng-change="vm.modelChanged(vm.animal)"
       ng-options="animal as animal.name for animal in vm.dropDownValues">
  </select>
  
  <span>{{vm.animal}}</span>
  <div>{{vm.actualModel}}</div>
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me, it isn't a best way. Is it possible to modify the model value when the model value is being changed? Something like `on('change')` in `jQuery`. So I can make some `callbacks` there.

Comment: You don't meed onchange, I will add the other solution

Comment: Thanks! But I decided to use `custom directive` to do this one as I think it will be better if it is reusable.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will be better if it is reusable. So I decided to use a custom directive to do this.

```js
var exampleApp = angular.module('exampleApp', []);

exampleApp.directive('ngModelToarray', function () {       
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
         scope.$watch(function () {
            return ngModel.$modelValue;
         }, function(newValue) {
            if( newValue && !Array.isArray(newValue) )
              ngModel.$setViewValue([newValue]);
         });
    }
  }
});   

exampleApp.controller('ExampleController', function ExampleController($scope) {
  $scope.districts = [
      {
        name: 'A'
      },
      {
        name: 'B'
      },
      {
        name: 'C'
      }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="exampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <select ng-options="district.name for district in districts" ng-model="selectedDistrict" ng-model-toarray></select>
    <p>{{selectedDistrict}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```